# Wii u 220 v adapter?

Tags: nintendo-wii

My friend bought me a WII U from US and the WII U adapter supports 110 voltage and where live, the 110 voltage is not supported. I don't know what voltage range is supported there. How can i find what voltage range is supported in my country? And what should i do to get my 110 v WII U worked?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at other devices. almost all the time they'll have the technical specification written/engraved somewhere on the device indicating wattage, voltage, serial numbers and stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your Wii U AC adapter - on the bottom, it should say the supported input voltages. On mine, since I purchased it, and live, in Australia, it says 230V-240V 50Hz. This will be different for different regions of the world.
For example, this one:
[image: Wii U AC adapter]
It supports 100V up to 240V at 50Hz or 60Hz - this one is basically universal. If yours is like this than the only thing you might need is a physical plug adapter so it will fit in your power socket.

You can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Table_of_mains_voltages_and_frequencies) to find your country's mains power voltage and frequency. Make sure your AC adapter voltage matches your country's! Otherwise it is most likely not going to work and would be dangerous to use.

If your country's mains voltage is not compatible with the AC adapter, there are converters available which (provided you get the correct one) will convert, say, 110V, to, say, 230V. But for the cost of those it might be best in that case to simply buy another Wii U AC adapter that is compatible for your country.

Comment: Please note: That PSU is a chinese copy, not an original one. Also an original one is universal, despite it not being indicated on the back.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Wii U in the US and I use it in Latin America where we use 220v. I plug the Wii U's AC adapter directly and it works. Same for the Wii U Gamepad AC adapter.